# Property Injection for Base Controller Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm trying to automatically set a property on any controller that derives from my `BaseController` class. Here is the code in my `Application_Start` method. The `UnitOfWork` property is always null when I try and access it.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
builder.RegisterType<VesteraTechnologiesContext>().As<IContext>();
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>();
builder.RegisterType<BaseController>()
       .OnActivated(c => c.Instance.UnitOfWork = c.Context.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>());
var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Here is what the BaseController looks like

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
}
```

The reason I'm trying to do this via a property instead on through a constructor is so that I don't have to duplicate the constructor in every controller that needs access to the `UnitOfWork` property, since constructors are not inherited.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Autofac by default registers the controllers to use constructor injection. To enable [property injection  with autofac](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html): you should use:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly)
       .PropertiesAutowired();
```

Comment: @nemesv thanks for the tip. Do you know that if this has any perf impact?

Comment: @tugberk I haven't used PropertiesAutowired in a production environment so I don't know how much perf impact it has. It uses reflection to find the public settable properties so it has at least the usual reflection costs.

Comment: @nemesv new link please

Comment: @Trikaldarshi thanks for noticing, I've updated the link.

Comment: @nemesv:  I have a basecontroller where I have a property to be injected, this is not helping me.

Answer (score -1):

> since constructors are not inherited.

Usually, it's possible to call the base constructor as follows:

```
public DescendantClass ()
  : base() 
{
}
```

Comment: The OP would need a constructor with an `IUnitOfWork` parameter.

Comment: GertArnold is correct, and I know I can cascade the constructors, but this is what I'm trying to avoid. Thanks.

Comment: Have a public constructor like this does nothing unless also wanting to provide a "default constructor" for an object with non-default constructors. The base constructor will automatically be called by the implicit "default constructor".